# Does Google offer reporting on use of the "Block all ... results" feature?

Tags: google, search-results

Does Google offer a way to report on how many people actually blocked results from my site from showing up in their results?

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/why-is-google-offering-users-the-ability-to-block-results-from-my-site) describes the behavior I'm asking about. I understand *why* its there, I want to know if I can get a report on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no report available for this. It would be nice to have in Google Webmaster Tools but as of now it does not exist.

Comment: Thats a shame. that is really valuable data.